# Python equivalent code to append two integers directly like in C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x

X  Y
So,I'm having two numbers. say, [12,3]
And I want to compare 123 with 321 i,e XY and YX
Or [1234,4] --->  12344<44321

If I directly try using append, that is not valid in python.
C++ code which does what I want->

```
int Compare(string X, string Y)
{
    // first append Y at the end of X
    string XY = X.append(Y);

    // then append X at the end of Y
    string YX = Y.append(X);

    // Now see which of the two formed numbers is greater
    if (XY > YX)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `extend`!?

Comment: I found out a way by converting to string, concatenating, and then converting to int again for comparing? Any other efficient way?

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan Can't directly use extend on integers. X.extend(Y) with X.Y being integers will give syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, seems that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly there is a mistake in your C++ code**

`XY=X.append(Y)` will also change X to X+Y
for example consider the following code snippet:

```
string X="ab", Y="cd";
string XY=X.append(Y);
cout<<"X="<<X<<", Y="<<Y<<", XY="<<XY;
```

output:

```
X=abcd, Y=cd, XY=abcd
```

Because append will first join Y in X then assign value of X to XY.
this will cause problem when you compute YX later.
I will suggest using '+' operator instead:

```
int Compare(string X, string Y)
{
    string XY = X+Y;
    string YX = Y+X;

    if (XY > YX) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

**Equivalent Python3 code would be**

```
def Compare(X, Y):
    X=str(X)   # Convert to string in case integer parameters are passed (if you are
    Y=str(Y)   # sure that only string will be passed you can skip these two lines)

    XY = X+Y
    YX = Y+X

    if (XY > YX):
        return 1
    else: 
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings in python using `+`. I.e., `"a" + "b"` results in the string `"ab"`. To convert a string into a number use `int()` constructor. I.e., `int("10")` will produce the number `10`.

This should provide you with enough information to form the solution to your problem.